# Syntax error upon this character ||

Tags: bash, shell

I have this:

```
set -e
(
    (
     docker stop html2pdf
     docker rm html2pdf
    ) || { echo; }
) &
```

I am just trying to run those commands in the background and ignore if one of them fails.

but then I get this error:

```
/home/oleg/codes/cm/html-to-pdf/scripts/run.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
```

Comment: Why not use command grouping instead of your outer, or both subshells?

Comment: i am not sure, can you show an example in an answer? mine is def over-convoluted

Comment: `{ { docker stop html2pdf; dockerrm html2pdf; } || { echo; }; } &`

Comment: thanks anything better than just `echo`?  I just want to ignore a failure but also log everything too

Comment: `{ commands ; } || : &`

Comment: My `bash` does not complain; `posh` does not complain. There is no line 13 in the snippet. Are you sure the error comes from this code?

Comment: the line in the snippet with the ||

Comment: Well, have you tried running the snippet and the snippet only? My point is it works fine. If you're getting `syntax error` from a larger code block, then maybe the snippet is not complete in terms of [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have the `set -e` in that script because that's part of your inherited environment.

An easy way is to just *ignore* that in the child:

```
( set +e ; docker stop html2pdf ; docker rm html2pdf ) &
```

Now inside the scope of the `(...)` code the `set -e` doesn't take effect and both commands execute.

Any command following will automatically execute (even if the `docker` commands fail) because of the backgrounding of the task.

e.g.

```
$ cat x
#!/bin/bash

set -e
( set +e ; docker stop html2pdf ; docker rm html2pdf ) &

echo hello

$ ./x
hello
$ Error response from daemon: No such container: html2pdf
Error: No such container: html2pdf
```

We can see both `docker` commands ran *and* the `echo` command ran.